# column is not getting dropped

Tags: python, pandas

Why column A is not getting dropped in train,valid,test data frames?

```
import pandas as pd 

train = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
test  = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
valid = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

for df in [train,valid,test]:
    df = df.drop(['A'],axis=1)

print('A' in train.columns)
print('A' in test.columns)
print('A' in valid.columns)
#True
#True
#True
```

Comment: unless you use `inplace=True` a lot of pandas methods will return copies. Use the flag, or reassign.

Comment: Also, note that reassigning is binding the changes to the name `df` which is being thrown away. Since the name is reassigned, you no longer are making changes to the original dataframes referenced by train/test/valid.

Comment: It is not dropped because you don't change the `df` from your list but actually reassign a new variable called `df` in your for loops. So yes you need to use `inplace=True` to change the actual `df` from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `inplace=True` parameter, because [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) function working also `inplace`:

```
for df in [train,valid,test]:
    df.drop(['A'],axis=1, inplace=True)

print('A' in train.columns)
False
print('A' in test.columns)
False
print('A' in valid.columns)
False
```

Reason why is not removed column is `df` is not assign back, so DataFrames are not changed.

---

Another idea is create list of DataFrames and assign each changed DataFrame back:

```
L = [train,valid,test]
for i in range(len(L)):
    L[i] = L[i].drop(['A'],axis=1)

print (L)
[   B  C
0  5  a
1  6  b
2  7  c
3  8  d
4  9  e,    B  C
0  5  a
1  6  b
2  7  c
3  8  d
4  9  e,    B  C
0  5  a
1  6  b
2  7  c
3  8  d
4  9  e]
```